# Android how to open local file in browser?

Tags: android

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
intent.setDataAndType(uri, "text/html");
File file = new File(uri.getPath());
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

the URI is

```
file:///data/user/0/com.carmate.crashreporter/files/crashResult.html
```

the browser is opened correctly also with the correct URI, however, it shows nothing

Comment: what is the logcat saying could be fileprovider?

Comment: The browser may not have rights to read the content at that filesystem path. Note that your code should crash on Android 7.0+ with a `FileUriExposedException`.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to show your local html content in the WebView?

Comment: Yeah, but the design is to open phone's default browser, and there is no activity since this project is to build an SDK and only got the application context.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but do you really need to do it? I think you better try to use a WebView or create an activity and show the content in a TextView using `Html.fromHtml()`.

You can do something like

```java
TextView view = findViewById(R.id.your_text_view);
view.setText(Html.fromHtml("<h1>Your html content </h1>"))
```

Comment: Hello Micael, welcome to SO. While this displays Html inside a TextView, this is absolutely suboptimal from any point of view. This is impractical to display large contents of HTML, let alone proper HTML/CSS, and potential scripting. In other instances, launching an intent let's the user pick what browser or tool to use to consume the content; Activities and webViews are fine for local content within an app, but sometimes you need to fire an intent.

Comment: Thanks, Michael. However, the design is to open phone's default browser, and there is no activity since this project is to build an SDK and only got the application context.

Comment: Well, so take a look at the cordova/phonegap project https://cordova.apache.org
I think you want to do something like that